# Can I perform my missed prayers with the same wuzu for obligatory prayers given that I have a medical condition requiring wuzu before each prayer?

Tags: women, wudu

I have problem of gas and [leukorrhea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leukorrhea). I know that I have to make ablution for each prayer when the time of prayer begins.

My question is: Can I perform my missed (or qaza) prayers with the same wuzu which I have done for that obligatory prayer?

In other words can I perform obligatory and missed prayers with one ablution while I have the problem of leukorrhea and gas?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can perform any type of prayer (salah), be it obligatory (wajib), past/due (qidha), recommended (mustahib) etc, if you have a valid widu/wizu.